# materialize css image slider position current image number

Tags: materialize

I‘ve done an image slider in materialize. works great. now I want to change other content depending on the actually shown image. how can I detect the slide position.

regards

Answer (score 0):

The following loop gives you the current tab/slide/image's position(position indexing starts with 0) which is active.I hope it helps.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('.slides').children().length; i++){
        if($('.slides').children()[i].className == "active")
          { 
             console.log(i);
          } 
     }
```

Comment: thanxs, are there more hints to this slider, I would like to start and stop videos when slide in out...

Comment: Are those videos embedded within slider list ?

Comment: yes, actually I check the index, when the element contains mp4; i start the video...  it's not very handy.

Comment: I agree, even I am facing a lot of issues .